# Field '___recordID' is not marked queryable

Tags: ios, cloudkit

I try to download all record with a specific recordType that recordID is not matches with a certain one.

But I get an error. Any idea? I thought I can mark as queryable only manually added fields.

`<CKError 0x15df2a10: "Invalid Arguments" (12/2015); server message = "Field '___recordID' is not marked queryable"; uuid = ECDD0C97-550F-4DD5-942D-AF4DF8917EEB; container ID = "iCloud.com.kukodajanos.Movie-Buffs">`

`let query = CKQuery(recordType: "UserSetting", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "recordID != %@", CKRecordID(recordName: loggedInUserRecordName!)))`

Answer (score 19):

I found. possible to add metaindexes as well.

[image]

Comment: This fixed the problem for me. But strangely, the app has been running fine for at least 6 months, before it suddenly stop pulling info from CloudKit last week. And I had to tick that box to fix syncing again.

Comment: I ran into this issue when trying to query a particular type using a predicate of the format "TRUEPREDICATE". Seems a little odd that you have to turn on an index on the record ID to return all the records of a type...

Answer (score 1):

You only need to manually set the Query index on ID if you choose NOT to use a predicate with your query. If you use a predicate on any self defined field name such as:

[image]

e.g.

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "UserRecordID = %@", selectedUser!.userRecordID!.recordName)
let query = CKQuery(recordType: recordType, predicate: predicate)
```

you will not experience this issue.